# Looking for software that will help script update statements faster

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a lot of mundane update statements I have to push through PLSQL and MSSQL and it requires a lot of editing. I will usually pull the data into excel than reformat it in notepad++ . This is pretty time consuming and I was wondering if there are any solutions for this?

```
UPDATE ATGSITES SET IPADDRESS = 'xxx' WHERE OWNSITEID = '270789'
UPDATE ATGSITES SET IPADDRESS = '1yyy' WHERE OWNSITEID = '270506'
UPDATE ATGSITES SET IPADDRESS = '158568' WHERE OWNSITEID = '27745'
```

X(35353) update statements

Comment: you may want to add sample statement like how it looks like in excel and final format you are doing

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure for Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can create a table of updates and perform a single join

```
UPDATE ATGSITES SET IPADDRESS = B.IPADDRESS
 From  ATGSITES A
 Join  NewTable B on A.OWNSITEID = B.OWNSITEID
```

Where NewTable has the structure of OWNSITEID and IPADDRESS

I would also add an index on OWNSITEID

Answer (score 0):

In Ms Sql Server

Save the data in a CSV text file delimited by comma  like that format

```
IPADDRESS   , OWNSITEID
xxx      ,270789
1yyy     ,270506
158568   ,27745
......
...........
```

suppose that the table to be updated is named: users_ip

Run the following script to update table from the text file

```
-- update table users_ip from csv file delimited wth , and first row is  header

-- create temp table for loading the text file
CREATE  TABLE #tmp_x (IPADDRESS nvarchar (10),OWNSITEID nvarchar(10))
go

-- import the csv file
BULK INSERT #tmp_x
FROM 'c:\temp\data.txt' --CSV file with header delimited by ,
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR =',',rowterminator = '\n',FIRSTROW = 2 )
go

update u
set u.IPADDRESS = t.IPADDRESS
from users_ip u
join #tmp_x t on  t.OWNSITEID = u.OWNSITEID

//drop the temp table
drop table #tmp_x
```

Comment: Thanks, If my answer satisfy you , mark it as answer